# How to convert from an ArrayList of arrays to an array of arrays

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

//edit: I changed my ArrayList conversion, but I am unable to load the second spinner

What am I doing wrong.  I would like to fill a second spinner with an array of w depending on the row selected in the first spinner, but am getting this warning when trying to convert from array list.

***I have this marked in code
Null Pointer Exception
11-06 19:03:34.050: WARN/System.err(5342):     at RetrievingAmazonXMLDataActivity.onCreate(RetrievingAmazonXMLDataActivity.java:88)

// edited code

```
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
            String a = dumpTitles("ProductName", i);
            element = a.split("!");
            allProducts.add(element);
        }

       w =  (String[][])allProducts.toArray(new String[allProducts.size()][]);


Spinner spinnerProducts = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spinnerProducts.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

// **** error line below

```
 ArrayAdapter<String> productsArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, productArrayToShow);

       productsArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerProducts.setAdapter(productsArrayAdapter);

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id)
    {

        try {
            selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();


            productArrayToShow = w[position];

        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
```

// original code

```
ArrayList<String[]>allProducts = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++) {
        String a = dumpTitles("ProductName", i);
        element = a.split("!");
        allProducts.add(element);
    }


    String[][] w; = new String[allProducts.size()][];
        for (int a = 0; a<allProducts.size(); a++) {
            w[a] = (String[])allProducts.toArray(new String[allProducts.size()]);
        }
```

Comment: Once a question has been answered, don't change it into a question about the next problem you run into. Post a new question.

Answer (score 9):

Why not just

```
String[][] w = allProducts.toArray(new String[][] {});
```

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you changed your mind about how you were going to do the conversion half way through. Your code is a bit of this:

```
String[][] w = new String[allProducts.size()][];
for (int a = 0; a<allProducts.size(); a++) {
  w[a] = allProducts.get(a);
}
```

and a bit of that:

```
String[][] w = allProducts.toArray(new String[allProducts.size()][]);
```

Either will work, though the latter is shorter, and possibly more efficient.

Comment: The `(String[][])` casting is redundant. You don't need that.

Comment: @tom You are correct. I have updated the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get by with just this:

```
String[][] w = allProducts.toArray(new String[allProducts.size()]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make them of the same datatype an "ArrayList" and a "Array of Strings" they are not of the same datatype, so they wont be compartable with each other. And please comment where the problem is.

Comment: like i have sad try to make sure you convert them to the same data types. For instance w[a] = Convert.ToString(allProducts[a])

Comment: Right, and that was the question--answering the "how do I convert these" with "you need to convert them" isn't that useful, that's all I'm saying.

Comment: it is very very usefull buddy. you have to convert them to the same type. if it is from ArrayList to String[] make sure the values are converted to Strings.

Comment: ... I'll try one more time. The original question was "how do I convert?" The answer isn't "you need to convert", the poster is already *trying* to convert, and was asking *how*. There's no conversion to strings involved, the issue is converting from List<String[]> to String[][]. They're asking how.

Comment: b patient with me Dave.try this code and see if it is not converting like i was saying. List<string> allProducts = new List<string>();
            allProducts.Add("12");
            String[] w = new String[1];
            w[0] = allProducts[0];
            Console.WriteLine(allProducts[0]);
            Console.ReadKey();

Comment: I really think you should just go back and re-read the question (well, not now that it's been changed). Again, all I'm saying is that when a question is "how do I convert this", the answer is "you need to convert that". The question was *how*. And your code doesn't answer the original question anyway; have you read the other solutions to understand both the question and the answer?

Comment: ok. mayb am felling dizzy its 3:38 where i am. i will look at it againg and i will post back the solution. please Sir, be patient with me.

Comment: There are already enough solutions; I'm not sure any more are required.

Comment: Thats great, it almost gave me a head-ache. Sir, can i tell you something ? but it does not regard the code problem